# How can I setup my discord bot to respond to an array of messages?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

(This is my first time using JavaScript). My current code does not return a response from my Bot. I would like for the Bot to be able to respond to an array of user-sent messages, so I created an array of potential inputs. I am struggling on knowing how to format the "if" statement. The image is what I currently have:
[Code snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XMZP.png)

I have tried changing 'includes' to 'indexof' and to change userMsg from 'const' to 'var,' though I haven't fully understood java syntax. Basically, what ends up happening is the Bot either responds to all messages or no messages...

Sorry if this was asked poorly. I have searched through some other questions and tried what I could but so far it has not worked.

Thank you for the help ♥

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discord.js API changes often enough so this may not be valid, but you can try this means of responding to certain inputs.

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

// Your array of messages to respond to
const messagesToRespond = ['hello', 'hi', 'hey'];

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('Bot is ready!');
});

client.on('messageCreate', message => {
  // Check if the message content matches any message in the array
  if (messagesToRespond.includes(message.content.toLowerCase())) {
    // Send a response
    message.channel.send('Hello! I am your friendly bot.');
  }
});

// Replace 'YOUR_BOT_TOKEN' with your actual bot token
client.login('YOUR_BOT_TOKEN');
```

Comment: This example is pretty simple, it can be advanced to respond uniquely to each response but code would need adjustments.

Comment: The client doesnt have the MessageContent intent

Comment: This may help then.

Comment: No issue at all.